# Link Intent Android

Tags: android, android-intent, share

In my android browser I can share the current link with google+, what's app and so on. Now I want my app to be listed there to. So I use the intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.SEND" />
                 <data android:scheme="http"/> 
            </intent-filter>
```

But now my app is only listed in the intent chooser when  I click a link. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<activity android:name=".ShareLink">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: It says "Parsing Error" when I try to install it.

Comment: upss, sorry, just delete metadata line. I edited my answer. It works now I tested.

Comment: And how do I get the link? Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
link = bundle.getString(???);

Comment: I didn't test it but I think you can it it like: Uri data = intent.getData();

Comment: URL url = new URL(data.getScheme(), data.getHost(), data.getPath())

Comment: oops - that doesn't - I get an exception.

Comment: look at the code sample under subject: Handle the Incoming Content. I tried now and it works I can get url with the example at developers page: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html